# MVC Cshtml page I want to create reverse case of below code ["ResponseMessage"]!=null && ["ResponseMessage"]!=""

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

else if (TempData["ResponseMessage"] != null && (String)@TempData["ResponseMessage"] != "")

Comment: `"I want to create reverse case"` what do you mean by? What are you trying to achieve?